# Make floated div remain on top of overflowing content

Tags: html, css

I would like to list links in a single line and hide anything that does not fit within browser width. In the end I would like to have a single div that is always on top of overflowing links. How can I achieve this?

Here's [demo on dablet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2900041), resize the browser window to see what I mean.

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="bar">
    <a href="">item</a>
    …
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>

    <div class="more">
        <a href="">more items...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS styles:**

```
.bar {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.bar a:link,
.bar a:visited {
    background-color: #b3d4ae;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #003300;
    padding: 0 3px 15px 3px;
}

.more {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: whould you like to have more items next to list?

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 there could be much more items in list, but they will be hidden if the do not fit in bworser. "more" link needs to always float right and appear next to right border of the browser.

Comment: you thought [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sajmon/tgVhW/1/) ?

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 like that, but "more items" needs to be on top of links, not below

Comment: so like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sajmon/tgVhW/2/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The result is:  [(demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2900057))

[image]
[image]
[image]

I change list of anchors in your markup to `ul` it is more semantic and good practice in web development

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link03</a></li>
        …
        <li><a href="#">link20</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="more">
        <a href="">more items...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS styles:**

```
.bar {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    /* .more width + ~15px to prevent half-visible links */
    padding-right: 83px;
}

.bar ul { margin: 0; }

.bar ul li {
    background-color: #b3d4ae;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #003300;
    padding: 0 3px;
    float: left;
}

.bar ul li a,
.bar ul li,
.more,
.more a {
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bar ul li + li {
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.more {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    box-shadow: -5px 0 5px #fff;
    /* fixed width for example */
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why fixed position is not appropriate in this scenario like Thai Phan suggested?

Comment: but you are actually hiding the `li` inside `more`

Comment: @DavidW, I have commented on Thai Phan's answer. Just scroll the page.

Comment: @Jashwant not hiding in `.more`, but cover with non-transparent `.more`

Comment: Yes, you are covering so you can always see the half anchors :) See my solution

Comment: @Jashwant i fixed it with fixed `width` for `.more` and same `padding-right` for `.bar`

Comment: @Jashwant as i know, it is common css practice

Comment: Why do links start so much inside?

Comment: In all my browsers links seem to start not from the left edge of the browser, but they look like they have left margin of 60 pixels

Comment: @DavidW May be it is default browsers styles. Are you using any kind of [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)? for you case you can add `.bar ul, .bar li {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` to style to reset default values for lists

Comment: No, not using any styles or resets. Even the demo link you provided shows it that way.

Comment: Please, show image of situation you described, and i will fix my answer immediately

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to copy Reddit with the "Edit" link on the top-right corner of the site? If that's the case, the following CSS that should do what you want.

```
.more {
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: @DavidW position fixed will position element relatively to whole document not parent div, it will be trouble in future. Without `background` on `.more` links will be visible anyway. So please, see my solution

Comment: Give your `body` a `height` of `200%` and scroll :)

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. It should've been position: absolute instead of position: fixed.

Comment: @ThaiPhan Yes and also div containing `.more` must have `position: relative` to make `position: absolute;` on child be applied

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Yeah, but I just assumed that was trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zdcDA/)

**CSS:**

```
.bar {
font-size: 12px;
height: 16px;
margin: 0 0 5px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.bar a:link, .bar a:visited {
background-color: #b3d4ae;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #003300;
padding: 0 3px 15px 3px;
}

.links{  
}
.more {
float: right; 
margin-left:20px; 
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<div class="bar">
<div class="more">
    <a href="">more items...</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the partial links too? Ones that are half hidden under "more items"

Comment: Half hidden ? I havent hide anything in `more items`

Comment: No, I mean, if item does not have enough space to show itself then it does not show at all, I was wondering if it can show partially under "more items"

Comment: Sorry, but I still dont get it. Can you show a layout diagram or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following style -

```
.bar {
font-size: 12px;
height: 16px;
margin: 0 0 5px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative
}
.bar a:link, .bar a:visited {
background-color: #b3d4ae;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #003300;
padding: 0 3px 15px 3px;
}
.more {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
top: 0px;
right: 0;
margin: 10px;
}
```